# Terminal does nothing when an unknown command is entered

Tags: bash

When I enter a command which is unknown on my system, instead of getting the usual `asdf: command not found` error message, the terminal sits there doing nothing. If I terminate it, sometimes I see nothing, but sometimes I see some python functions receiving a keyboard interrupt, for example

```
$ asd
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>

import codecs
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 8, in <module>
    """#"
KeyboardInterrupt
```

or

```
$ cpioquw
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 5, in <module>
    from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function
KeyboardInterrupt
```

or

```
$ asdf
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>

    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 546, in main
    known_paths = addsitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 328, in addsitepackages
addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 190, in addsitedir
    names = os.listdir(sitedir)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

There seems to be no consistency in the messages at all, and I've never seen this happen before. Any ideas about where the issue might be coming from or how I might start to investigate?

Removing `.bashrc` doesn't appear to have any effect, and neither does trying in the virtual terminals either. I made a new user and the behaviour there is as expected. I'm guessing that the problem is in one of my `bash` config files, but I don't know which ones I should be checking.

I also tried reinstalling the `command-not-found` package, which had no effect either.

I've now tried

```
sudo apt-get purge command-not-found command-not-found-data
```

and it throws up an error which might mean something:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge command-not-found command-not-found-data 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bbswitch-dkms dkms lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libcuda1-331 libvdpau1 nvidia-prime
  nvidia-settings python-gdbm screen-resolution-extra
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED
  command-not-found* command-not-found-data* python3-commandnotfound*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 3 to remove and 238 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 4,205 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 287818 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing command-not-found (0.3ubuntu12) ...
Purging configuration files for command-not-found (0.3ubuntu12) ...
Removing python3-commandnotfound (0.3ubuntu12) ...
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /usr/bin/py3clean on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
dpkg: error processing package python3-commandnotfound (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
  File "/usr/bin/py3compile", line 4
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc2' in file /usr/bin/py3compile on line 4, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Removing command-not-found-data (0.3ubuntu12) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-commandnotfound
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Upon doing this, I noticed that if I run `python` or `python3` I end up running the same version, 2.7.6. Might this have something to do with the problem?

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: Actually, it is almost certainly an ubuntu derivative.  With ubuntu, if you type in an unknown command `asdf`, it runs `/usr/lib/command-not-found -- asdf`.  This checks for typos etc.  Try running that command directly to see if you get better errors.

Comment: Running `/usr/lib/command-not-found -- asdf` does the same thing as trying to run a non-existent command. I've checked, and the script exists.

Comment: The data files may have become corrupted. I would uninstall/purge command-not-found and command-not-found-data and re-install.   Check everything is gone from /usr/share/command-not-found before re-installing.

Comment: I made an edit above with the result of your suggestion.

Comment: Can you do `python3 --version`?

Comment: Same result - Python 2.7.6.

Comment: Yeah, looks like your python3 is pointing to the python2 executable, and python2 is not configured for UTF, so is getting confused.  Perhaps install python3?

Answer (score 0):

If you type `declare -f -p`, bash will list all defined shell functions. If there is a function named `command_not_found_handle`, that function will be invoked instead of the shell's usual behavior (only in bash 4). Presumably, in your case, that shell function is hanging.

(On my Debian system, that function is defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which is run by `/etc/profile`, which is the systemwide startup file for all Bournelike shells. All it does is invoke the `command-not-found` command, which is the Python script you're seeing a traceback from.)